# Where would I find the attributes of the related object using ParsePy?

Tags: python, parse-platform, parsepy

I am using the `ParsePy` from https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy to access our Parse DB (it works really easy, almost out of the box for me, btw).

The problem I have is that want to get joined data from two classes.
We have a `UserVote` class that is linked to the User class.
According to the example I see that I can use the `select_related` to get the attributes of User as well as those of UserVote.

The question is how would I access the attributes of the related object?
Specifically User has an attribute named `username` and I can't find it also under `vote` or under `vote.user` anywhere.

I am running the following code:

```
allvotes = UserVote.Query.all().select_related("User")
for vote in allvotes:
   if hasattr(vote, 'username') or hasattr(vote, 'user') and hasattr(vote.user, 'username'):
            print vote
```

In the debugger I do see that I get votes, and that there is an attribute `vote.user` but I find no vote that holds a username as I expected.

I get no output for the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saw that no one answered and meanwhile I got it working as follows, not sure why I was having problems initially, probably some UserVote records had no user pointer.

This is the query I use to retrieve the userVotes -

```py
votes = UserVote.Query.filter(public=True,user__exists=True).order_by("-createdAt").select_related("user")
```

And then basically I can use use vote.user.username or for any other user attribute